# How to save one Doctrine entity to two database tables (required for MySQL optimisation)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, blob, database-optimization

In my database I've a table `file` and a table `file_content`. The `file` table stores the metadata of the file such as `name`, `mime` and some more. The `file_content` stores a blob with the file content. I'm not storing the blob in the same table as the metadata for performance reasons only.

For a 'version 2' of my project I'm looking into Doctrine (2.3). To me, a "File" seems to be one entity, with properties such as `name`, `mime`, `extension`, `content` that should be used like this:

```
$file = new File();
$file->setName('hello.txt');
$file->setMime('text/plain');
$file->setContent('Hello world!')
$em->persist($file);
$em->flush();
```

Is this behaviour possible? To me it makes no sense to create two entities for something that's really just one entity. I could not find anything about it in the documentation and I read in a 2-year-old topic that it isn't possible in Doctrine 2.1: [Doctrine 2.1 - Map entity to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198271/doctrine-2-1-map-entity-to-multiple-tables)

Someone any suggestions how to handle this correctly? I'm new to Doctrine and have been playing around with it a bit to see if it's the right choice for my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the ability to alter the schema of your database? If so, I'd consider consolidating this into one table.

Barring that, you may want to try a one-to-one relationship in Doctrine. Perhaps something like:

```
class File {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $mime;
    private $content;
}

class Content {
    private $id;
    private $data;
    private $fileId;
}
```

If you map Content->fileId with a one-to-one relationship to File->id, then you can do things like:

```
$file->getContent()->getData();
$file->getContent()->setData("something different");
```

Here's some more info on one-to-one mappings: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: I have the ability to change the database schema, but it would harm performance really badly (always put BLOB and TEXT fields in separate tables when dealing with over 10K rows). So that's not an option.

I'll have a look into the one-to-one relationships. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the one-to-one solution is the only solution for this, so I'm accepting this answer. I don't think it is very elegant since the content is not a separate entity, but only there to optimise the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a different approach even though it's a somewhat older question. Instead of making two entities, you should make three.

Create FileMetadata, which holds name, mimetype, etc. Create FileContent, which holds the content. Then, create a third entity File which holds a one-to-one connection with one of each of the other types, and give it a bunch of methods that simply call the matching methods on the sub entities.

So for example in File, the setName method would look like this:

```
  public function setName() {
    $this->getFileMetadata()->getName();
  }
```

And set would look like this:

```
  public function setName( $name ) {
    $this->getFileMetadata()->setName( $name );
  }
```

The constructor of the File entity should create a new FileMetadata and a new FileContent on creation and should NOT have a setFilemetadata or setFilecontent method; these two entities should be completely shielded from your application.

Now you have the File entity, which handles exactly like you want (a single entity, no additional sub-entities) which is still stored neatly in two (well, three really) different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could map both tables, resulting in `File` and `FileContent`, and add a one-to-one relationship between the two.
Then add getter/setter methods for the file content in the `File` class. In these you'd have to call the corresponding methods in `FileContent`.