# Doctrine 2: multiple tables - one entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, multiple-tables

How can I map multiple tables with identical structure to entity?

For example we have these tables :

- Object_001 (id, name, lat, long)
- Object_002 (id, name, lat, long)
- Object_003 (id, name, lat, long)
- ..........
- Object_41000 (id, name, lat, long)
- ..........
- Object_xxxxx (id, name, lat, long)

**Object Defination**

```
class Object {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $lat;
    private $long;
}
```

I found similar problem: [Doctrine 2.1 - Map entity to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198271/doctrine-2-1-map-entity-to-multiple-tables) and one of answer is **physically merge the tables together in MySQL**, but in my case I need **seperated tables**

Help would appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: You don't. You might try creating a view which merges your tables together but I doubt if that will work for you.

Comment: @SeantheBean, questions are completely different, so this question is not a dublicate. The question you mention is about __merging multi table data__ into a single entity. However, what is asked here is he has n identical tables and he asks whether it is possible to map those tables into a single entity so that they are __represented by that single entity independently.__

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood the question. I don't think that's something Doctrine supports, so your best bet would be a workaround like what @Cerad suggested.