# One entity to multiple tables with symfony/doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony

### Introduction

I'm working on a symfony3 project and I have a lot of different "types" for certain entities. What I mean by this is that, I have a `TypeUser`, `TypeEvent`, `TypeMeeting` tables.

These tables will only have an `id` and a `label`.

### Problem:

When using doctrine, I can link 1 entity to 1 table using the anotations, like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="TypeUser")
 */
```

However, I would like this part to be completely generic. How can I specify the Table name depending on the type I need?

Is there another alternative when using Doctrine other than the annotations to make this possible?

I would really like to avoid making `n` entities for `n` tables, when they are very similar in name and in structure.

### Question:

Is it possible to make one generic entity to match a specific TypeXXXX table, to reduce redundancy? If so how would I go about doing it?

---

Similar [Doctrine 2.1 - Map entity to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198271/doctrine-2-1-map-entity-to-multiple-tables)

---

[Symfony book on doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Comment: Inheritance is probably your best bet: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html.  Of course I would sort of wonder about your design but that is a different issue.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the comment. I did think about that, but I wanted to avoid inheritance as well. Why would you wonder about the design? Bad practice?

Comment: Depends on the app of course.  Duplicate types can be a bit of a red flag.  But maybe not.

Comment: @Cerad that's a really good point. I could eventually make a third column in the type and just specify "typeName" and have that set as "user", "meeting", etc

Comment: Speaking of design, could you not have solved your problem by doing entity relationships between your main table and the several possible types, instead of repeating tables?